# application/empty при отправке фэйкового файла в ларавел

Tags: laravel, fileupload, phpunit, testng

Пишу http тест загрузки файла и получаю ошибку application/empty при запуске тестов
Мой тест:

```
public function testUploadContract() {

    $user = User::where('id', '=', $this->companyId)->first();
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    Storage::fake('files');
    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.pdf', 100, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
    $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => "Bearer $token", 'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'])->withoutExceptionHandling()->post('/api/v2/company/documents/upload', ['file' => $file]);
    $response->dump();
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Мой контроллер:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request);
    if ($request->hasFile('file') == false) {
        // dump($request->file());
        return response()
            ->json([
                'title' => 'Ошибка',
                'message' => 'Не передан файл с реестром!'
            ], 400, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE || JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }

    $validMimeTypes = [
        'application/pdf',
    ];
    $mimeType = mime_content_type($request->file->getPathname());
    if (in_array($mimeType, $validMimeTypes) == false) {
        return response()
            ->json([
                'title' => 'Ошибка',
                'message' => 'Плохой тип файла (' . $mimeType . ')'
            ], 400, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE || JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('temp', $request->file('file'));
    $url = Storage::disk('public')->url($path);

    Log::channel('debug')->debug("FILE IS $url");

    return response()
        ->json([
            'title' => 'Файл загружен',
            'message' => 'Файл успешно загружен',
            'path' => $path,
            'preview' => Storage::disk('public')->url($path)
        ], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE || JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```

Когда я загружаю файл с клиента как положено, то всё отлично, а в тестах такой вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И последнее что могу приложить сейчас это дамп файла от фэйкера:   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста чем можете, я уже правда не знаю, что с этим поделать(

Comment: Если необходимо больше информации, то напишите мне пожалуйста - предоставлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тестах используется такая конструкция:

```
UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.pdf', 100, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

Посмотрим в сорцах, что делает `create()`:

```
public function create($name, $kilobytes = 0, $mimeType = null)
{
    if (is_string($kilobytes)) {
        return $this->createWithContent($name, $kilobytes);
    }

    return tap(new File($name, tmpfile()), function ($file) use ($kilobytes, $mimeType) {
        $file->sizeToReport = $kilobytes * 1024;
        $file->mimeTypeToReport = $mimeType;
    });
}
```

Получается, mime-тип проставляется просто как свойство объекта `UploadedFile`, а содержимое файла - пустое.

Проверяем через тинкер: `php artisan tinker`:

```
$file = Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.pdf', 100, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);

// "Content-Type" => "application/pdf" - передал клиент
$file->getMimeType();

// "" - пусто
$file->getContent();

// "application/x-empty"
mime_content_type($file->getRealPath());
```

В контроллере mime-тип определяется по содержимому (которое пустое):

```
mime_content_type($request->file->getPathname());
```

Поэтому `application/x-empty`.

Как исправить?

Нужно подготовить реальный pdf-файл, и использовать `createWithContent()`. При генерации фейковых изображений через `image()` именно так и делается.

Проверим снова через тинкер:

```
$file = Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent('file.pdf', file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/file_1_k.pdf'));

// "application/pdf"
mime_content_type($file->getRealPath());
```

Также лучше исправить в контроллере определение типа на `$request->file->getMimeType()`.

Тут также, как и в `mime_content_type()` происходит реальное определение типа файла по содержимому. Если посмотреть сорцы, используется `finfo()`, либо вызов оболочки `file -b --mime` - есть две реализации.

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо, чувак). Я пока ещё не проверил правильность, но боялся, что сложный вопрос и никто не ответит. Обязательно сегодня протестирую и приму ответ если покатит

Comment: Товарищи, этот чел гений и оно работает, все почести ему). Я не нашёл ни одного полноценного дубликата на эту тему в других источниках и соответственно подобного ответа тоже не было